# Opening files take minutes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, performance, blob-cache

We installed a Sharepoint 2013 server with a separate Database in a OOTB default configuration.

The issue we have is that the first user (in a period of time) who tries to open a file has to wait minutes. All other users after that have no problems at all with opening the other files. Files open instantly.

Blob cache is enabled and we implemented a Powershell wake-up script (running every 10 min) to keep the front-end 'awake'.  Our document library is still under 1K files. What can cause this issue?

Comment: What size of files are in question? Which file type(s)? Do you have BLOB cache enabled?

Comment: @moe Blob cache is enabled (default settings). The files are between a few hundred kb's - 10 mb

Comment: Still seems like the recycle of IIS that is performed every night. How are the files accessed?